# Windows phone tile text color displaying wrong

Tags: windows-phone-7, text, colors, windows-phone-7.1

In my windows phone application I created a tile with dark blue text, when I set the tile and my app starts up the tile looks correct except that the text aka the name of the app on the tile is reset to display white for some reason. I have a version with black text but the same problem occurs.

Is there some standard that all windows phone tiles text should be white? Quite amazing that they can reset the text color on a straight png image...

Anyways, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have another part of code that updates your tile (may be in your App.xaml.cs or in a Background Agent)? It would be helpful if you can drop a code snippet to understand the issue.

Comment: Not at all done in code, it automatically gets picked up if you set the Background.png and ApplicationIcon.png images in the project

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to display application name in the tile through image.

Clearing the **Title** text property under Project's Properties -> **Tile Options** section will do, but this would show an error in VS2010.

To remove the default Tile Title, open WMAppManifest.xml (this should be under Properties folder) in the editor.

Under <Tokens> section you will find details related to tiles. Clear the text inside <Title> tag, save and recompile.

I did this in one of my projects, the final XML snippet looks like below (note the empty <Title> tag).

```xml
<Tokens>
    <PrimaryToken TokenID="MyAppToken" TaskName="_default">
    <TemplateType5>
        <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Background.png</BackgroundImageURI>
        <Count>0</Count>
        <Title></Title>
    </TemplateType5>
    </PrimaryToken>
</Tokens>
```